# How to use mysql trigger between 2 database server

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 database server from different computer. Let says that my branch PC have their own database and I need the branch data automatically update to my own PC. I need a trigger in my branch MYSQL that update the data to my PC MYSQL.

Comment: MySQL does not have that functionality.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen so replication is not a thing in mysql? O_O

Comment: Also, that's offtopic.

Comment: @iehrlich Trigger and database link is not a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest sense, MySQL does not allow connections to other servers<sup>1</sup>. It allows replication, but that's not quite the same thing. You also probably don't want to make your home PC a read-only replication of the production DB. That often is very messy.

It would not be a trigger, but polling could work. You would need to have some application-level logic to copy information from one server into another. You might run this daily, hourly, etc. to actively copy the data.

---

<sup>1. [`marriadb`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-external-table-types/) does have a sense of table replication, but not triggers.</sup>